# jquery Event.stopPropagation() seems not to work

Tags: jquery, events

Am I totally missing what this is supposed to do? I expect that if I call stopPropagation() on an event, handlers for that event won't get triggered on ancestor elements, but the example below isn't working that way (in FireFox 3 at least)..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input").live("click", function(event){
        console.log("input click handler called")
        event.stopPropagation()
    });

    $("body").live("click", function(event){
        console.log("body was click handler called. event.isPropagationStopped() returns: " + event.isPropagationStopped());
    })

</script>

 ...

<body>
    <input type="text" >
</body>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Live events don't follow the same event bubbling rules.  See the documentation on [live event handling](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn).

Quote from reference above:

> Live events do not bubble in the
>   traditional manner and cannot be
>   stopped using stopPropagation or
>   stopImmediatePropagation. For example,
>   take the case of two click events -
>   one bound to "li" and another "li a".
>   Should a click occur on the inner
>   anchor BOTH events will be triggered.
>   This is because when a
>   $("li").bind("click", fn); is bound
>   you're actually saying "Whenever a
>   click event occurs on an LI element -
>   or inside an LI element - trigger this
>   click event." To stop further
>   processing for a live event, fn must
>   return false.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for the clarificatin.

Comment: I'm asking the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961418/is-it-possible-to-stop-child-click-events-propagating-to-parents-when-handled-by the thing is, what does one do when you have to stop propagation on live events, i don't have the choice of removing the live handler as I'm dealing with dynamically loaded elements.