# Jquery click event propagation

Tags: jquery, events, click

I have a table with click events bound to its rows (`<tr>`). There are `<a>` elements inside those rows with their own click events assigned.

Problem is, when i click on the `<a>`  element, it also fires the click event from the parent `<tr>`. I don't want this behavior; I just want to fire the `<a>` click event.

Code:

```
 // Event row TR

 $("tr:not(:first)").click(function() {
    $(".window, .backFundo, .close").remove();

    var position = $(this).offset().top;
    position = position < 0 ? 20 : position;

    $("body").append( $("<div></div>").addClass("backFundo") );
    $("body").append( $("<div></div>").addClass("window")
         .html("<span class=close><img src=Images/close.png id=fechar /></span>")
      .append( "<span class=titulo>O que deseja fazer?</span>"
              +"<span class=crud><a href=# id=edit>Editar</a></span>"
              +"<span class=crud><a href=# id=delete codigo=" 
              + $(this).children("td:first").html() 
              + ">Excluir</a></span>" )
       .css({top:"20px"})
       .fadeIn("slow") );

    $(document).scrollTop(0);
 });

 // <A> Element event

 $("a").live("click",function() { alert("clicked!"); });
```

Whenever you click the anchor it fires event from it parent row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 28):

You have to stop event bubbling. In jQuery you can do this by

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

in the onclick event of the anchor tag.

```
$("a").live("click",function(e){alert("clicked!");e.stopPropagation();});
```

***Edit***

See this post

**[jquery Event.stopPropagation() seems not to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122375/jquery-event-stoppropagation-seems-not-to-work)**

Comment: I've a normal table.Then I create new anchor elements promagamatically,and append to that rows.

Comment: Try giving return false at the end of the anchor event handler.

Comment: Add a `e.preventDefault();` in there as well for good measure, there's some browser inconsistency between propagation prevention.

Comment: `return false` as well as `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default click action (going to linked page) to happen  - which is obviously not what OP wants

Answer (score 4):

I would use `bind` instead of `live` for both `<tr>` and `<a>` and the following code

`$("a").bind("click", function(e){ alert("clicked!"); e.stopPropagation() });`

for `<a>`.

All `<a href>`'s will work as expected and `<tr>` event handler code won't execute after clicking `<a>`.

Works in all modern browsers.