# Prevent click from child firing parent click event

Tags: jquery, click

I have a selector that binds a click event which will remove the popup. However, I only want the selector to handle the click, instead of the children of the selector to be able to fire the click event.

My code:

```
<div id="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

When clicking on `.popup-content`, it will fire the click event when I don't want the children of `#popup` to do so.

The jQuery Code:

```
$('#popup').bind('click', function()
{
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery click event propagation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244320/jquery-click-event-propagation)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try:

```
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
```

in your event handler

Comment: `return false` is the same as calling `e.stopPropagation()` *and* `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know much about the use of `stopPropagation`, thanks!

Comment: +1, thanks for this, I too did not know about `stopPropagation()`

Comment: e.stopPropagation not work when a link <a> is the parent of element that has click event. Just e.prevent default and return false are work. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 17):

In your event handler for `#popup` check if `e.target == this`. i.e.:

```
$('#popup').bind('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target == this) $(this).remove();
});
```

Doing this is much easier than binding extra click handlers to all the children.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative example to handle the parent click, but allow children to have their own handlers. Exactly what I needed to check for. I used `if(!$(e.target).is('a'))` instead of `if(e.target == this)`, but this set me on the right track.

Comment: I needed to use if(!$(e.target).is('a')) as well. I used it in 'each' function (maybe using a loop determines the solution)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.popup-content').bind('click', function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

or

```
$('.popup-content').bind('click', function(e)
{
    return false;
});
```

In your case - it's same, but sometimes you can't do such thing without e.stopPropagation(). For example:

```
$('.popup-content a').bind('click', function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    return confirm("Are you sure?");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{if(e.target == this ){ return;}});
```