# Enable click on only one child jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following html

```
<li clas='k-item'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<span>ABC</span>
</li>
```

Is there any way I can bind click to **only** `input` and disable for `span` and `li`?

This is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work

```
$('.k-item').on('click', function (e) {
     $(this).unbind('click');
            if ($(e.target).is('input')) {
                $('input').bind('click');
            }
});
```

I do not have much experience with jquery

Comment: perhaps this? http://jsfiddle.net/exj8cvnv/ I don't know what .k-item and the span does, but it seems you can disable them when clicking the input. Do you want to disable these events permanently or juts for instance? If they have to depend on the input, you should listen to the .change event and trigger the click events of the parent and the span. can you please clearly explain what is the expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent click from child firing parent click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929198/prevent-click-from-child-firing-parent-click-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just target the `input` to begin with? You can then use e.stopPropagation() to prevent the LI from getting the click event (which is I gather your aim):

```
$('.k-item input').click(function (e) {
    // Stop the LI from firing a click event
    e.stopPropagation();
    // input is clicked
});
```

Comment: There is already click event assigned to complete li dynamically

Comment: @Richa: Can you please clarify the actual aim of the code, as your original makes no sense out of context? :)

Comment: I have an li that is generated dynamically and has some click event assigned to it by kendo. Now i want to somehow unbind that click event from all li and have it only on input

Comment: @Richa: Just use `stopPropagation` to stop the click from getting to the LI. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
$('.k-item input').click(function(){
   //modify the rest handler code...
});
```

**Update:** if click is defined for li, and you don't want that to be triggered on child span then you will need to stop event propagation.

```
$('.k-item span').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();//do not trigger parent click on child span
});
```

Comment: I want to disable li click that is already defined dynamically. So i can't do above

Answer (score 0):

You need only this:

```
$('.k-item').on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('input')) {// or event.target.type
               //do stuff
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select the desired element and apply the event listener:

```
$('.k-item > input').on('click', function() { // ...  });
```