# Fire event on click on a div except a link

Tags: jquery

I want to fire an event when I click on a div, but i don't want that event to fire if i click on a specific link on that div:

my JS

```
$("#myDiv").not("#myLink").click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
});

//Or

$("#myDiv:not(#myLink)".click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
});

$("body").on('click', '#myLink', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

my HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <a href="#" id="myLink">Some link</a>
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjDdN/9/)

**EDIT:** Actually my real code is with "**On**" method, I've already tried stopPropagation but it doesn't work in that case

Comment: May be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244320/jquery-click-event-propagation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get your desired result you have to register an event handler on the anchor element, that when executed blocks the event propagation.

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Why this work?**

Events propogate starting from the root element till the target element (capture phase) and after reaching the target, 
they climb up back to the root element (bubbling phase). 
The target element is the element that received the event.

It's possible to register event listeners both on the capture phase, both on the bubbling phase.
Here, we're using jQuery that registers the event on the bubbling phase.

`stopPropagation` permits to block the event propagation through the DOM.

That's an article I wrote, in case you need more info about [W3C event model](https://brunoscopelliti.com/about-events/).

Comment: Actually my real code is with "On" method, I've already tried stopPropagation but it doesn't work in that case

Comment: @Anas I udated the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/bruscopelliti/SjDdN/10/ it works even using the on() method... check it out

Answer (score 4):

To not have to repeat the code stopping from executing for every link you put in divs, you can use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

```
$('#myDiv a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //stops default link action
    //do your stuff
});
```

This will stop all links (`<a>`) from executing the way they normally do if they're within the `#myDiv` div.

Answer (score 0):

this may also work

```
$("#myDiv").click(function (ev) {
     alert("clicked");


}).children().click(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SjDdN/7/