# JQuery error in IE, works with FF. Maybe a problem with live

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have an ASP.net MVC2 application. In wich I'm using JQuery to alter all table rows so I can click anywhere in any row to trigger a click event on a link in the clicked row.

The tables is created using MVC's built in partialview ajax.

Here is my JQuery script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table tr').live('click',function (event) {
                $('#asplink', this).trigger('click');
            })
            .live('mouseenter',function (event) {
                this.bgColor = 'lightblue';                    
            })
            .live('mouseleave', function (event) {
                this.bgColor = 'white';
            });

        });

</script>
```

And this is the first part of the partial view code that creates the table.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.JobHeaderData)
   { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="asplink" href="http://localhost/sagstyring/EditJob.asp?JobDataID=<%: item.JobDataId %>&JobNumId=<%: item.JobNumID%>&JobNum=<%: item.JobNumID%>&DepId=1&User_Id=<%:ViewData["UserId"]%>" onclick="window.open(this.href,'Rediger sag <%: item.JobNumID %> ', 'status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, resizeable=0, scrollbars=0, width=900, height=700'); return false;">Rediger</a>                 
        </td>
```

In firefox this works perfectly. In IE, JQuery crashes when I click on a row.

If I debug the page in IE. I get this.

```
Out of stack space
```

In jquery-1.4.1.js line 1822

```
 // Trigger the event, it is assumed that "handle" is a function
    var handle = jQuery.data( elem, "handle" );
    if ( handle ) {
        handle.apply( elem, data );
    }
```

I'm no eagle at javascript, so I'm pretty much stuck.

Edit: IE had a problem with spaces in my window.open function on the click event. Having fixed that, I can now see that the click event is actualy working, but it enters a Loop. I just keeps clicking on the link until I get the Out of stack space error.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

This works.

```
$('table tr').live('click', function (event) {                    
                window.open(jQuery(this).find(".asplink").attr('href'), 'Edit', 'status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, width=900, height=700');                               
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('table tr').live('click',function (event) {
    $('#asplink', this).trigger('click');
    return false;
})
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122375/jquery-event-stoppropagation-seems-not-to-work), it looks like doing `event.stopPropogation();` won't work with live and you'll need to use `return false;`.  I'm not sure why this would be a problem in IE but not Firefox though.

Comment: Doesn't work either. I've tried it with both class and id reference. It still enters a loop. The link is opened several times until the main page throws a "Stack overflow"

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('table tr').live('click',function (event) {
  $(this).find('#asplink').trigger('click');

})
```

scratch that.

looking at your code again, i really think it's the fact that all the rows have the same id. try giving them all theclass aslpink instead of the id.  and change the jquery  to:

```
$('table tr').live('click',function (event) {
  $(this).find('.asplink').trigger('click');

})
```

hmmmm ok:
try giving the rows all a unique id.  something like `id='#asplink<%=JobId%>'`  and use

```
$(this).find('.asplink').click();
```

is there other tables on the page?

Comment: Same error. Diffenrent place in JQuery it fails. 

Line 1593.

if ( !handle ) {
   eventHandle = function() {
    // Handle the second event of a trigger and when
    // an event is called after a page has unloaded
    return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && !jQuery.event.triggered ?
     jQuery.event.handle.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
     undefined;
   };

   handle = jQuery.data( elem, "handle", eventHandle );
  }

Comment: out of curiosity:  what happens if you just call .click() instead of .trigger('click')
also:  i just noticed:   #asplink is a selector for everything with the ID  asplink.  do you have more then one thing on your page with the same Id?  this might be what's throwing IE off.

Comment: Just tried with .click instead of trigger. It still works in FF, but in IE I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method", but the click event is still executed. Every row in my table will have a link with the same id. If I change it into a class, I get an out of memory error instead.

Comment: "Every row in my table will have a link with the same id." This is a violation of the HTML specification, which says that every id on a page must be unique.  I suggest making that a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the asplink class on your anchor tags try adding this code to your document on ready:

```
$('a.asplink').live('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropogation();
}
```

This should prevent the click event on the anchor tag from bubbling up to the td tag and triggering the click event on the anchor tag again.

Comment: This code have the same effect as calling click instead of trigger('click'). I get an "Message: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Line: 37
Char: 21

This is the event.stop.... line