# Is it possible to stop child click events propagating to parents when handled by .live()?

Tags: html, jquery, nested

I have 'Back Board' on my images and content over here: http://syndex.me
So basically, you click on an image, it will overlay a info panel above the clicked content.

I want to do two things:

- Click on the background of the site to fade out the currently opened info panel
- Be able to click on a tag, link, or social icon **within** the info panel without triggering it's parent function, which is too fade out again.

I cannot use stopPropagation for the child click being superseded by the parent click as i need the click events to be handled by .live() [(see documentation)](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) This is due to the fact that posts are being dynamically loaded.

I cannot just say something like:
   $("#Background").click(function(){//fade out the Info Board}
Because that is being covered by the entire post wrapper, and i can't put an event ont hat because then I'm even deeper in the dilemma of parents taking over children's events :-)

So far I'm at least able to have just one infoboard open (i.e I click on one image, then another, it will close the already opened one, and open the current one. So this part is all good:

```
    $('.theContent:not(.clicked)').live("click", function () {
            $(this).children('.postInfo').fadeIn(400);
            $(".clicked").each(function() {
                    $(this).find('.postInfo').fadeOut(400);
                    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
            });
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
 });
     $('.clicked').live("click", function () {
            $(".clicked").each(function() {
                $(this).find('.postInfo').fadeOut(400);
                $(this).removeClass('clicked');
            });
 });
```

Re .live(), .delegate() and .stopPropogation():

> *Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers, therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.*

Comment: I'm not sure if it works but have you tried `return false;` on your `live()` event handler?

Comment: Nope, just did now though and it makes no difference. That would have been seriously zen though!

Comment: In 'normal' JavaScript, that's what you're supposed to do :) It seems that there's no way to stop the event. Have you thought of perhaps setting a global var and checking for it on your animation handler?

Comment: I've never done that before, I'll look into global vars in the meantime. I'm sure this is a common problem though. Lots of UI lately has this click outside click inside approach.

Comment: Hm....any idea why it worked? http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/PbxBH/2/

Comment: I guess the version on my site is super nested. That does work though, wonder why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about simply checking whether the event actually took place on the specific element:

```
function activate(el) {
    el.find('.postInfo').fadeIn(400);
    el.addClass('clicked');
}
function deactivate(el) {
    el.find('.postInfo').fadeOut(400);
    el.removeClass('clicked');
}
$('.theContent:not(.clicked)').live('click', function(e) {
    deactivate($('.clicked'));
    activate($(this));
});

$('.clicked').live("click", function(e) {
    if (! $(e.target).is('a')) {
        // this should not trigger if a click occured on one of the links
        deactivate($(this));
    }
});

$('#ape').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('#ape')) {
        deactivate($('.clicked'));
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add `el.addClass('clicked');` aspect, this is the marker that says, ok, i've been clicked. I assumed you put this in the activate function, if that's the case, it cancels itself out: http://syndex.me. Ack.

Comment: @RGBK Yes, I forgot that line and I had to revert the deactivate/activate calls. I've updated the code, give it a try.

Comment: That fixed the issue, and i missed the inverted calls, thanks. It still doesn't deactivate the parent though. I'm wondering, maybe it's because the target is'nt accurate yet? I'm researching target at the moment to understand it better, seems like a useful function.

Comment: It's the same thing for the background, that's why I didn't include the code initially. I've added now a handler that should take care of that as well.

Comment: You know what, i'm happy with clicking outside the info panel closing it. What do you reckon? Then i dont have to worry about the .clicked not working (still isnt) I traced the element being clicked when i click on say, the heart icon, and it says "div". That may be because it's nested in so many other elements. There is an a there though. I think this will suffice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about [binding](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) the click event when the post is dynamically loaded?  This way you can use stopPropagation().

http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/CzEj5/

Comment: Wait I thought that bind does not deal with future elements only the current ones? I'll try it though and see.

Comment: Like i thought bind does not recognise the newly loaded content, which comes from another script.

Comment: @RGBK, ah. If the content is being loaded from a script that you do not control, then you can't use this approach.  Do you have control over the HTML?  You can always wrap a div around the dynamic content and catch the click there.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the event to a parent element, it won't stop its propagation event to it's childrens.

You have two solutions, to bind an event to every children and put THERE the stop propagation call, or just test who ired the click event in the parent. I prsonaly find more elegant the second solution.

You can read something more about it here :
http://redfishmemories.blogspot.it/2014/08/jquery-prevent-event-propagation-and.html