# jquerys' e.stopPropagation() cannot get required functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`photoContainer` below has children. This works okay, but if I click on any of its children the code execute, hides blackLayer and removes `photoContainer`. How can I prevent this from happening and yet execute when I click anywhere but on `photoContainer` children ?

Thanks.

```
$('div#photoContainer').live('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var blackLayer = $('div#blackLayer');
    if (blackLayer.length) {
        blackLayer.fadeOut();
    }
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: A quick search would lead you to this exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122375/jquery-event-stoppropagation-seems-not-to-work.

Comment: great, but return false; does not work in this particular case. I don't see why the -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are stopping the propagation of the event on the parent element, you want to stop the propagation of the event on the children of the `#photoContainer` element so it does not propagate up to the `#phoeoContainer` element:

```
$('#photoContainer').live('click', function (e) {
    var blackLayer = $('div#blackLayer');
    if (blackLayer.length) {
        blackLayer.fadeOut();
    }
    $(this).remove();
});
$('#photoContainer > div').live('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will stop the propagation of the click event when it is triggered on a child `div` of the `#photoContainer` element.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J9dBS/2/ (notice that if you click on the "child" element that no alert is shown)

I would like to note that `.live()` is deprecidated as of jQuery 1.7. If you are using jQuery 1.7 or later then it's suggested to use `.on()` like this:

```
$(<root-element>).on(<event>, <selector>, <event-handler>)
```

Or if you are using jQuery 1.4.2 to jQuery 1.6.4 then it's suggested that you use `.delegate()`:

```
$(<root-element>).delegate(<selector>, <event>, <event-handler>);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the issue and providing an actual working answer, rather than leaving a stupid irrelevant comment. (You're missing a `'click', function(event)` - on the second function).